# laravel 5.1 - retrieving data from 2 table and sending it to index page using foreach

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, foreach

I am retrieving data from two different tables - `users` and `phones` - and sending them to a view page. My code is pulling all the columns from the phone table:

Controller.php:

```
public function index()
    {
       $alluser=User::with('phone')->get();
       return view('index',compact('alluser'));

    }
```

view.blade.php:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Mobile</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
        @foreach($alluser as $user)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$user->phone}}</td>

        </tr>
        @endforeach                                   
    </tbody>
</table>
```

result:[image: its pulling all the columns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `->with("phone")` will return an object attached to your `user` accessed via `->phone`, which is why your `mobile` column has a json object with all the phone `columns` in it.

If you just want to show each user's name and their phone number, change

```
<td>{{$user->phone}}</td>
```

to

```
<td>{{$user->phone->phone}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify an additional query to select the desired columns,

```
User::with(['phone' => function ($query) {
    $query->select(['id', 'phone']);
}])->get();
```

And then,

```
$user->phone->phone //not $user->phone
```